# CSS element positioning trouble

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how can I get the heading element to flow under the slider instead of on top and behind the slider. In other words how can I get the heading or any other element to flow normaly below the slider.

Here is the link to the Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1kg7s473/

HTML

```
<form class="sliders">
    <input type="radio" name="slider-choice" id="first-slider" checked />
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider">
            <p>Some Random Text...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="second-slider" class="prev"></label>
            <label for="second-slider" class="next"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="radio" name="slider-choice" id="second-slider" />
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider">
            <p>Even Some More Random Text...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="first-slider" class="prev"></label>
            <label for="first-slider" class="next"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<h2>Some more random text</h2>
```

CSS

```
.sliders {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

.sliders input{ 
    display: none; 
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 600px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

.nav label {
    margin-top: 65px;
    width: 85px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: black;
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .6);
    Z-index: 99999;
}

.sliders:hover .nav label{
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sliders:hover .prev:hover, .sliders:hover .next:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav .next{ 
    right: 0;
}

.prev:before{
    content: '\2770';
}

.next:before{
    content: '\2771';
}

input:checked + .slider-container .slider{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slider-container .nav label{ 
    display: block; 
}

p{
    padding: 100px 20px;
    width: 560px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #dae1ef;
}
```

Comment: That's because your slider container has zero height, since all its contents are absolutely positioned and hence taken out of the flow. You will have to set a height for the element.

Comment: @Terry but what if the height is dynamic what can be done then?

Comment: Depends on what kind of dynamic you are talking about. If the height is always a proportion of a viewport dimension, you can still use CSS only by using the vw or vh units. Otherwise, you'll have to use JS—and that will be very messy (because you will also have to recalculate on viewport resize events, and any other JS/DOM changes that will alter the slider dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

Put the `h2` inside a `div` like this:

```
<div class="h2Container" >
 <h2>Some more random text</h2>
</div>
```

Add the following CSS to the class `h2Container`

```
.h2Container
{
position: relative; padding-top: 25%;    
}
```

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1kg7s473/2/) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the styles on the `.slider`class and attribute them to the slides container instead with these changes too:

```
.slider-container {
   width: 600px;
   position: relative; //do not use absolute on this
   top: 0;
   height: 235px; //you must have a height defined or 100%
   display: inline-block; //this reserves the entire area (width X Height) and automatically places the next element below the defined height 
}
```

See the working [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbqvyY)